# "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object. Are you sending a JSON object with valid key names?"

Tags: json, bash, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All,

I am trying to upload a simple JSON slug that should meet the specs and keep getting an error from Firebase on the command line.

here is a sample of the JSON

[{"act":"draw","arg":"20","art":"650.923","block":7207397,"deleted":false,"id":4387,"ink":"10.351568024950279","ire":"643.796950752935","lad":"0x25b8CCE3fD037c11226C64980e4128480A932eBc","pip":"120.68","per":"1.0404295226106932","ratio":"199.675367095938625390002206918521800","tab":"1299.732889761896578547364065340249904","time":"2019-02-11T16:21:48.000Z","tx":"0xda74c7780d0b778b99ddf35c0d45ad24aa088b320b7e15169badd4c261ca9f76","idx":72,"timestamp":1549902108000},{"act":"open","arg":"","art":"0","block":6746816,"deleted":false,"id":4387,"ink":"0","ire":"0","lad":"0x3e294e9EA60249999839d829CDAFE9bC3A67Cef4","pip":"131.01","per":"1.0350112435677474","ratio":null,"tab":"0.000000000000000000","time":"2018-11-21T17:25:31.000Z","tx":"0x71f513384fd358b4e945bb7b5e55f49f3a3e61f157333211e91fa0f3f7df0715","idx":103,"timestamp":1542821131000}]

bash $ curl -X PATCH -d @4387.json https://cname.firebaseio.com/data/.json?auth=xxxxxxxx

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're showing is not a JSON object.  It's a JSON array.  You can tell because it begins and ends with square brackets.  If there is just one JSON object element in the array, perhaps you meant to extract the one item and make it the input here.

Comment: fair point... firebase should be able to accept an array also.. I am testing on macos, so it might also be the curl syntax.. testing now

Comment: No, Firebase does not accept arrays at the top level.  You will need to provide an object.  That's why you're getting this error message.

Comment: To my knowledge (albeit in learning mode), it does accepted nested objects in the form of a file.. no?

Comment: ok.. figured it out.. a simple {  "data":     on the front.. and a } on the back.. and it nested uploads and posts...

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue in flutter with firebase. The solution is to use **json.encode('json object here')**. It's resolved my issue.